# Angular directive taking no effect

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new to angular and I am trying to build my first directive, but it's not rendering inside my HTML.

Here is my HTML page : the directive is called at the bottom of the HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="store">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-controller="storeController as store">
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="product in store.product">
            <h3 >
                <product-name></product-name>
            </h3>
</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my app.js :

```
(function(){
var app = angular.module("store",[]);
var gem = [
    {
    name: "Dodec",
    price: 2.95,
    canPurchase: true,
    soldOut: false,
    reviews: []
    },
    {
    name: "Panta",
    price: 20.4,
    canPurchase: true,
    soldOut: false,
    reviews: []
    }
];
app.controller("storeController",function(){
    this.product = gem;
});

app.controller("tabController",function($scope){
    $scope.tab = 1;
    $scope.SetTab = function(value){
        $scope.tab = value;
    };

    $scope.IsSet = function(value){
        return value === $scope.tab;
    }
});

app.controller("ReviewController", function($scope){
    $scope.review = "";

    $scope.addReview = function(product){
        product.reviews.push($scope.review);
        $scope.review = "";
    };

});

app.directive("productName",function(){
    return {
        restrict : "E",
        templateUrl : "product-name.html"
    };
});




})();
```

notice the directive at the end.

And finally here is my product-name.html file :

```
{{product.name}}
<em class="pull-right"> {{product.price | currency}}</em>
```

What did I do wrong? why is the directive not behaving like it should?

Thanks

Comment: At first glance I'd check to make sure that the path to your template is correct. Easiest check is to look for a 404 error in your browser console window.

Comment: NO error found, I clicked the product-name.html and it works.

Comment: Not sure what's going on... just copied your examples above into a plnkr and all seems to be working fine, see here: http://plnkr.co/edit/tVKDKSVQQCHH4ZuK7dBl?p=preview

Comment: wow thats interesting.

Comment: That one isn't exactly working fine. Notice the styles aren't applied in the @Brocco plnk. See Plnk in my answer below for details but directive templates must have only one root element.

Comment: @irth good catch, I missed that he was using bootstrap, was just trying to get the template was rendering

Comment: Yeah actually all I care about is to render the template, but still not rendering in my browser. Man this thing really giving me a headache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my server, I downloaded the http server from here https://github.com/nodeapps/http-server then started it and the directive shows up now.

Answer (score 2):

In product-name.html, AngularJS directive templates must have one root element.

I wrapped the html in divs in [this plnkr.](http://plnkr.co/edit/EOxRsccKJ9uFbujefzDR?p=preview)

```
<div>
 {{product.name}}
 <em class="pull-right"> {{product.price | currency}}</em>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe a CORS problem? What does Chrome Dev Tools > Network tell you? Do you see an XHR request?

Comment: even ng-include is taking no effect.

Comment: sounds like version issues. double check all your bower deps or try to only use cdn's like the plnk.

Comment: What kind of errors? We can't help with vague statements.